# how to load and process very large size data file in R

Tags: python, r, statistics, bigdata

I have to process some very large size data files in a project, these files are reallly big size, each one size > 50G. the format of these file is vary neat:

```
type1  vaue1:123
type2  vaue1:234
type2  vaue1:234
type1  vaue1:234
type3  vaue1:234
.......
```

I want to find out how much a specific type and calculate the mean value and median value of this type.
I use python to read the data file one by one and calculate in the end, but this is very slow. I want use R to help me with this but I wonder if R can process these large size data. I doubt if R can read these data into a data frame.

if someone konw some skill to process with large size data with R or something else tool. I really need some advises now!

Comment: *"I really need some advises"* is not an appropriate question for SO (or, for that matter, a question at all). There are many resources elsewhere on the internet for processing "big data" using R, I suggest you do some research.

Comment: Advice: python should be fine, you don't need to move to R.

Answer (score 1):

A relatively fast way to read your data would be using `fread` from the package `data.table`

```
d <- fread("myfile.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ":")
summary(d$V2)
```

[I assume you have 50 gigs of RAM to load the whole file.]